# image is not loading from url in glide on android kikat and lollipop

Tags: android, image, ssl

glide is showing error when we load image from url  in android lollipop and kitkat version .
and same url is working on above lollipop version in android.

we are using cdn for loading images.
its showing ssl error.

```
11-02 10:39:06.581 14611-14611/com.maangal_maangal.maangal E/exception: com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
    There was 1 cause:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException(java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
11-02 10:42:10.977 14611-14611/com.maangal_maangal.maangal E/exception: com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
    There was 1 cause:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException(java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
```

Comment: Pass the url without https

Comment: what is the solution for production of app. it will work without https in production